# Cannot enable Backup for GKE because 'Etcd alias ip must be enabled'

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, backup

Since I lost data because I removed (accidently) a namepace including a persistant volume, I am trying to enable Backup for my GKE cluster.

But after I try to enable it I get the message:

'Etcd alias ip must be enabled for Backup for GKE addon.'

I cannot find anything when searching for this, I do not know (or understand) how to enable Etcd alias ip. Does someone know what I can do?

Comment: What version is your GKE cluster?

Comment: If you have a zonal cluster and are running 1.24 or later, you may need to wait a bit as a change is rolling out in the background.  You might want to open a support case as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I just updated to version 1.24.5-gke.600, because on another cluster with older version I was able to update.

Comment: I have this issue with 1.24.12-gke.500 also.

Comment: And like @Martijn it worked several days later.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the replies, I just tried again and now it is working. I don't know why, did not make any other changes.